# Why netflix conductor does not provide a way to run tasks/subworkflows asynchronously?

Tags: netflix-conductor

Only several task can be run async: HTTP, EVENT, KAFKA. But why there is no a way to run SIMPLE tasks async. Especially would be very useful feature to run sub workflows async. The only workaround(and only for subworkflows) is to send event which will be handled by registered event which will run workflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm late to the party here, but check out the FORK operator.

https://orkes.io/content/docs/reference-docs/fork-task

[image: fork diagram]

In this workflow the fork splits your workflow into 3 paths - to send an email, SMS and a HTTP notification.  Each path runs asynch.  You can also set your JOIN (the other half of the fork) to JOIN_ON all or just some of the fork "tines"

If you need to define the number of asynchronous flows at runtime - the Dynamic Fork is the way to go (but it is a bit more complicated to set up).

https://orkes.io/content/docs/reference-docs/dynamic-fork-task

Comment: Interesting point, thanks for idea